# Get separate C# classes using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/9gElou/2

There I want to get separate c# classes using regex, I mean I want to match:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="settings")]
public sealed class Settings {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="gazelle_description")]
    public string Gazelle_description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="gazelle_authkey")]
    public string Gazelle_authkey { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="gazelle_pass")]
    public string Gazelle_pass { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="server")]
public sealed class Server {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="network")]
    public string Network { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="serverNames")]
    public string ServerNames { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="channelNames")]
    public string ChannelNames { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="announcerNames")]
    public string AnnouncerNames { get; set; }
}
```

separately.

My regex matches entire classes instead of getting them separately.

Where is my mistake:

`\[XmlRoot\(ElementName="\w+"\)\]\s+public sealed class \w+ \{(\s+[\]\(\)\w\d_="\[\{\};<>]+)+` ?

Comment: You need to make your regex lazy, [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/9gElou/4)

Comment: You need to use an appropriate tool to parse C# source code, not just a single regex.

Comment: You'd be better off using Roslyn for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

`\[XmlRoot\(ElementName="\w+"\)\]\s+public sealed class \w+ \{[\]\(\)\w\d="\[\{\};<>\s]+?\}\s*\}`

The character set needs to match lazily. See the usage of `+?` above.
Also, the end of the class is defined as two `}` with or without whitespaces between them - `\}\s*\}`.

Moreover,

1. I removed the capture group since it wasn't required.
2. `\w` already contains `_` so I removed that from the character set.
3. `\s` is added to the character set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9gElou/7)